# How to connect to Microsoft Dynamics Rms 2.0 Running sql2008r2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2019, microsoft-dynamics

Would anyone know anything about Microsoft Dynamics Rms 2.0 (2012)? We are having trouble connecting our sql server to the client side cashier (windows 10 pro) this software sunset in 2016 I believe and Microsoft won’t help. (We used an emergency ticket) So the “cashier”, doesn’t see the database, however it will see the server it’s self. When ever using ole ob connection the server is seen but not able to be connected to. We have opened every port on both computers to test to see if we could establish a connection, but to no avail... I have spent 16 hours on this with several people and can’t figure it out.

Here is the original question asked here https://www.facebook.com/groups/thisisanitsupportgroup/permalink/2698630683716128/

Covers a lot of what I have already done so

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need SQL Server 2005 backwards compatibility components installed at the client PC for that version of RMS to connect to any SQL Server newer than 2005 if I recall correctly.  Good luck finding a download link. Microsoft seems to have nuked all of them from what I can tell.  If you are taking over support of a system, search for an msi installer package named "SQLServer2005_BC_x64.msi" or x86. You probably want x64 on any newer clients though.  Hopefully you have a local copy already in an install folder somewhere assuming the previous RMS clients needed it to connect to the same DB Server.

Hope this helps.